# Estimates for the Dedekind number $M(9)$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, order-theory, open-problem

The [Dedekind number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number) $M(n)$ is the number of antichains in the partial order of subsets of $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$. It is only known for $0 \leq n \leq 8$.

**Question.** What are some known upper and lower bounds for $M(9)$?

Comment: Why is the [section on asymptotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number#Asymptotics) insufficient?

Comment: Because asymptotics do not tell us anything about concrete values, right?

Comment: does it not say that $2^{126} \leq M(9) \leq 1.106 \cdot 2^{126}$? These seem like concrete values...

Comment: @MrTsjolder: I do not see how this follows from the Wikipedia article, since the Landau symbols only tell us what happens for $n \to \infty$. This is obviously not the kind of mathematics that I am used to. Perhaps you can elaborate on this in a proper answer?

Comment: As a naive computer scientist I tend to take the big O notation as upper boundary, but indeed this is not guaranteed because the upper boundary only counts as from a certain $c$ which is unknown (I did not read through the proof). The lower bound on the other hand is quite concrete... PS: safer bounds could be $2^{126} \leq M(9) \leq 2^{252}$ using monotonicity of the Dedekind numbers...

Comment: Yes, but this estimate is obviously not very precise.